# TOS DI variable in tMySqlInput

Tags: mysql, talend

I'm relatively new to Talend OSDI. I managed to do simple request in MySql with **tMySqlInput** component. However today I have a more ambitious request and have some trouble to make it work.
Indeed I need a request where the result depends on the previous line. I made it on MySQLWorkbench but not on Talend. Exemple : delay time between two dates.
Here is the request :

```
SET @var = NULL;
SELECT id, start_date, end_date, @var precedent, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMEDIFF(start_date,@var)) AS diff, @var:=start_date AS temp
FROM ma_table
ORDER BY start_date;
```

and errors are :

- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT id, start_date, end_date, id_process_type, @var precedent, UNIX_TIMESTAMP' at line 2

...Not very usefull, Is this syntax forbidden on Talend ? Do it exists others solutions to do such requests on Talend ? (for delay time between two dates for examples) or other component maybe ? I am searching with tMysqlRow.

Thanks for ideas !

Comment: Can you post an example of your data and your expected output? I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you're doing there.

Comment: Yes of course. For example, a piece of my input data :

    `id    start_date             end_date    
    1     29-07-10 12:00:00      29-07-10 12:30:00
    2     29-07-10 13:00:00      29-07-10 13:35:00
    3     29-07-10 14:06:00      29-07-10 14:32:00`

and the output is the average delay between each start_date which is here 01:02:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Gabriele B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696436/gabriele-b) mentions, you might want to consider doing this in a more "Talend" way.

I'd personally make use of the tMemorizeRows component to do this though.

[image: Job layout]

To simplify this I've gone and made the start and end dates as integers but it should be trivial to handle this using proper dates.

[image: Sample data]

If we have some data that shows the start and end date of a process and we want to work out the delay between finishing the last one and starting the next process we can read all of the data in and then use the tMemorizeRows component to remember the last 2 rows:

[image: tMemorizeRows component configuration]

We then access the memorized data by looking at the array index. So here we go to a tJavaRow component that has an extra output column, `startdelay`. We then calculate it by comparing the current process' start day minus the last process' end date:

```
output_row.id = input_row.id;
output_row.startdate = input_row.startdate;
output_row.enddate = input_row.enddate; 
if (id_tMemorizeRows_1[0] != 1) {
    output_row.startDelay = startdate_tMemorizeRows_1[0] - enddate_tMemorizeRows_1[1];
} else {
    output_row.startDelay = 0;
}
```

The conditional statement it to avoid null pointer errors on the first run of the data as the `enddate_tMemorizeRows_1[1]` will be null at that point. You could handle the null in other ways of course.

This process is reasonably easy to understand and maintain (although there is that small bit of Java code in there) and has the benefits of only needing the load the data once and only keep a small part of it in memory at any one time. It should also be very fast.

Comment: your solution is absolutely elegant! +1 (maybe a little cryptic for a TOS newbie...the java part, i mean)

Comment: Indeed I took this solution, nice use of tMemorizeRows, I discovered the java part in a talend project. Just had to add a _tAggregateRow_ in order to do the average of the delay. Had some trouble with date<>int<>long but it's done :) Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You should consider a statement refactory to do it in a "Talend" way, maybe little slower but most portable and robust.

If your table is not huge, for example, I would recommend to load it in memory using tCacheOutput/tCacheInput (you can find them on Talend Exchange) and this design:

```
    tMySqlLoad----->tCacheOutput_1
        |
        |
        |            
    OnSubjobOk        
        |
        |
        v
  tCacheInput_1------->tMap_1--------+
                                     |
                                     |
                                   tJoin-------------->tMap_3------------>[output]
                                     |
                                     |
  tCacheInput_2------->tMap_2--------'
```

1. First of all you dump your table on a memory buffer
2. Then, you read two times this buffer. It's in memory, so it won't hurt performances
3. In tMap_1 you add a auto_increment index using a `Numeric.sequence`
4. You do the same in tMap_2 but with a starting number of 2 (basically, you shift the index)
5. Then you auto-join the table using these brand new columns
6. Finally in tMap_3 you're going to release your payload (ie make the diff)

This is going to be a verbose but robust solution if your table is small. If it's not and performance is not a issue you can try an even more verbose solution like [Prepared Statements](http://gabrielebaldassarre.com/2014/03/16/using-rdbms-prepared-statements-increase-efficiency-security-talend-queries/).

Comment: I'd be interested to know what the differences are between the tCache components and the tHash components that Talend supplies. I can't see anything at a quick glance but I've not played with the tCache components before.

Comment: if you look at the generated java code, you would find a well refined components set. I like the idea of being able to store the buffer on memory and/or disk and to be able to garbage it when you don't need it anymore. Still some bugs there, though (unfortunately the author have not plans of updating them anymore).

Comment: Interesting, I do not have thought this way, I'll try it and mark as accepted if I managed to do it. I might have a big table so I'll explore both solutions

Comment: if your table is 2-3M rows you should be safe, stated that you're working on a 64bit environment and you raised up your heap size in job configuration options to up to 3Gb (or even more).